# Higher-order component (HOC) in React causing extra rendering of wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, higher-order-components

I'm using `HOC` to be able to wrap all components which should have translations. Each component has its translation file which is imported dynamically. Also they share some shared functionality. So, I've created `HOC`, which is a function taking component as an argument returning component with some extra features(e.g. modified `componentDidMount`).

Below is `App.js` and `Translate.js`(`HOC`).

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import translated from './Translate';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      translation: {
        a: '',
      },
      translationRecieved: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('APP mounted')
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log('APP did update')
      if(!this.state.translationRecieved) {
         this.setState({
           translation: this.props.translation,
           translationRecieved: true
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('APP renders')
    const { t } = this.props
    const { a } = this.state.translation

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <p>This is state: a is {a}</p>
          <hr/>
          <p>Translated `a` is {t(a)}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Apptranslated = translated(App);

export default Apptranslated ;
```

**Translate.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import en from './en.json';

const translated  = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            translation: null
        }
    }  

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('HOC mounted')
      this.setState({
          translation: en
      })  
    }

    componentDidUpdate () {
      console.log('HOC did update')
    }


    translate = (val = '') => `**| ${val} |**`;

    render() {

      console.log('HOC renders')
      return <WrappedComponent 
        translation={this.state.translation} t={this.translate} {...this.props}/>;
    }
  }

  return HOC;
};

export default translated;
```

Instead of define logic of loading translation in every component, I've used `HOC`. `HOC` loads translations into `HOC`'s `state` and then pass it to wrapped component through the mechanism of `props`. Wrapped component receives passed `props` and saves it to the `state` (in `componentDidUpdate`). So my lifecycles are:

```
HOC renders
APP renders
APP mounted
HOC mounted
----initial phase ended---
----HOC fetched resources---
HOC renders
APP renders
APP did update
HOC did update
----APP modifies its state---
APP renders
APP did update
```

If I did the same with repetitive code (defining logic in each component)

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import en from './en.json';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      translation: {
        a: '',
      },
      translationRecieved: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('APP mounted')
    if(!this.state.translationRecieved) {
      this.setState({
        translation: en,
        translationRecieved: true
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log('APP did update')
  }

  translate = (val = '') => `**| ${val} |**`;

  render() {
    console.log('APP renders')
    const { a } = this.state.translation

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <p>This is state: a is {a}</p>
          <hr/>
          <p>Translated `a` is {this.translate(a)}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I would get

```
APP renders
APP mounted
APP renders
APP did update
```

Thus, I've extra rendering because I'm putting translations coming as props into component state. Why? Because they come **async**. So I've a choice: either write some logic in component to check whether translations have arrived and if not have some fallback options, or wait until they come and use `state` to safely use them in my `App` component.

Am I missing something or doing it wrong way? Or it is normal behavior of `HOC`?
Maybe `Redux` can solve this issue.

Comment: If the translations are loaded async you don't really have much choice. You can't delay rendering, so either you defer the render until you have everything, or you render a placeholder.

Comment: I've added code. 
What are the techniques to I defer rendering? Is it considered a bad practice?

Comment: I would imagine, `if (!a) return null;` from inside `render()`

Comment: @EdwardSammutAlessi it solved my problem.Thanks!